# Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have seen a lot of "answers" to this question but none of the answers seem to apply to me. I have a React JavaScript project generated by CRA. Now I would like to convert it to a project that accepts TypeScript files. So I remove jsconfig.json and add tsconfig.json then I start getting this error when I do a simple 'yarn start' (which translates to 'react-scripts start'). If I rollback (removing the tsconfig.json and adding back the jsconfig.json the error goes away. I really would like to move to TypeScript but so far I am stopped.

The tsconfig.json is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": false
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

The jsconfig.json is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```